# Tensorflow toco tool converted Conv2D to DepthwiseConv2DNative, but simplified graph does not produce the same results as the original

Tags: python, tensorflow

Context: I have two Tensorflow graphs that ideally should produce the same result for image segmentation. (The model comes from [here](https://github.com/jakeret/tf_unet)). The first graph is the "original" graph, while the second graph is a simplified version after running the toco tool on the first graph and setting the input to a fixed size (in this case, 1,572,572,1).

The command I used was `bazel run //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco – --drop_control_dependency --input_file=$MODEL_DIR/unet.pb --output_file=$MODEL_DIR/unet_bn.pb --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --input_shape=1,572,572,1 --input_array=x --output_array=output_map/Relu`

Unfortunately, toco does not yet seem to support the Exponential operator, so I have run both graphs with the same input up to the same point partway through the graph. The two graphs do not produce the same results. The difference starts after the first convolution.

I noticed that the [original model has a Conv2D operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3niPn.png) whereas the
[simplified model uses DepthwiseConv2dNative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8egW.png).

Upon examining the Tensorflow toco source code, it appears that one of the graph transforms it performs is converting "pure" convolutions to depthwise convolutions [as seen here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/convert_pure_conv_to_depthwise.cc), and one of the conditions for doing so is if the input shape has 1 feature channel (i.e. input_array.shape().dims(3) == 1), which is indeed the case for the first convolution in the model, but not for subsequent convolutions.

So I see why this conversion is taking place, but after this conversion, the two graphs do not produce the same result! Is there an explanation as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation, it appears that the simplified results are "mostly correct".

By that, I mean that directly comparing both graph's output tensors by using `==` will evaluate to false because the two tensors are not identically equal.

However, if I permit a tolerance level, in this case, `1e-04` as such:
`print(np.allclose(reference_results, simplified_results, rtol=1e-04)`, it evaluates to true.

So the error could perhaps be due to floating point accumulation or some other small discrepancy, but I believe it does not suggest some larger systematic error.